# How to send current user's(person using the app), Firebase Id token,from the Flutter app, to restapi, using http POST method?

Tags: node.js, firebase, http, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have created an app using flutter for UI and Restapi in nodejs as the backend. Now i want to verify the user, who signuped with the firebase authentication,the sending the current user's firebase Id token. In order, to do this I am sending the id token using the HTTP Post method. But got an error.

**Sample code:**

```
        import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
       if(user!=null){
  Future<IdTokenResult> idtoken = user.getIdToken();
    }
 http.Response response = await http.post("https://www.something.com/something/something",
                              body:jsonEncode({
                                "name": name.text,
                                "pincode": "$pincode",
                                "token": idtoken,
                                "phone": "${widget.phoneNo}",
                              }),
                                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                              );
```

**Got Error:**

```
     Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Future<IdTokenResult>'
```

**P.S: Suggest an edit, if something wrong with the question, I am for ideas** *(Thanks for the help in advance :) )*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need token(String) not idtoken(IdTokenResult)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

if(user!=null){
  IdTokenResult idtoken = await user.getIdToken(); 
  // get String token  
  String token = idtoken.token;
}
 http.Response response = await http.post("https://www.something.com/something/something",
                              body:jsonEncode({
                                "name": name.text,
                                "pincode": "$pincode",
                                "token": token,
                                "phone": "${widget.phoneNo}",
                              }),
                                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                              );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Taym95. So, in the rest api side, firebase-admin sdk, require only **token** not other parameters like time of creation,or expiration time, uid? to verify the current users?

Comment: Yes, firebase-admin needs only token(String) and you can thank me by upvoting the answer as correct so the others can benefit from the answer!!

Comment: Can we do like this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50295533/13462594

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is getIdToken() part.

Can you try below code please:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then(user => {
        if (user != null) {
           user.getIdToken().then(token => {
              http.Response response = await http.post("https://www.something.com/something/something",
                              body:jsonEncode({
                                "name": name.text,
                                "pincode": "$pincode",
                                "token": token,
                                "phone": "${widget.phoneNo}",
                              }),
                                  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                              );
        }
});
```