# HTTP Post request from Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions, xmlhttprequest, flutter-web, flutter-http

I have a function on Google Cloud Functions that I am trying to make a post request to in my Flutter web app. I tested a post request in Python and it worked with the following request:

```
params = {'input_key':'input_value'}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
r = requests.post("https://us-central1-lucid-bond-261904.cloudfunctions.net/cloudFunction", data=jason.dumps(params), headers=headers)
```

But when I try to do the same request from my Flutter web app using the http package, I keep getting an XMLHttpRequest error. Here's my http request in my flutter web app

```
String path = "https://us-central1-lucid-bond-261904.cloudfunctions.net/cloudFunction";
Map params = {'input_key':'input_value'}
var response = await http.post(path, body: json.encode(params), headers: <String, String>{'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
```

I know it successfully triggers the cloud function, because the first thing I have the cloud function do is print 'hello' to the log. It seems to maybe be an error in the way I'm choosing the content-type. [I read this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278258/http-post-with-json-on-body-flutter-dart) that implies that the content type might be getting changed to "application/json; charset=utf-8", but the fix that they specified doesn't apply to Flutter Web because the dart io package doesn't work on Flutter Web. **So how do I correctly specify the content type?** Or is there a better flutter package to use for this situation?

The error thrown back in Flutter is:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 264:20      get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 84:22
```

And the error in my Cloud Function

```
line 99, in cloudFunction shop_name = inputs_dict['input_key'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**EDIT:** Just tried doing the same post request from Postman and it worked successfully. Still not working from my flutter app though. Do I need to enable CORS or something in the Google Cloud Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally made it work. In my cloud function, request.get_json() was returning null. When I added the paramter force=True, it finally worked. I didn't have to do force=True when trigger the function through python or postman, but for some reason triggering it through flutter required the force=true.

```
request.get_json(force=True)
```

Comment: Great, great and great research! I had a completeley same situation (post request was curl command callable but from flutte web unable to send it) and solved it with your solution. For those who came up with this situation, It is not CORS problem!

Comment: facing the same issue, could you please describe a bit more here, where are you writing this request.get_json(force=True) ? in server side or flutter ?