# How to send body as a raw in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, httprequest, dio

I can try on swagger or postman, that is working but i cannot send request in flutter. This is the output of Postman =>

```
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '"12312412543412"'
```

This is my code api part in flutter =>

```
Future loginComplete(id, token) async {
    final response = await dio.post('${wp.LoginCompletePage}userId=$id',
      data: "$token",
      options: Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader:"application/json",
            HttpHeaders.acceptHeader:"*/*"
      }));
    debugPrint(response.toString());
    if(response.statusCode != 200) {
      debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());
    }
    return response;
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278258/http-post-with-json-on-body-flutter-dart

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you got the token but i think you need add this.

**final data = json.encode({"token": token});**

this works for me.

```
 Future loginComplete(id, token) async {
    
  final data = json.encode({"token": token});
    
   final response = await dio.post('${wp.LoginCompletePage}userId=$id',
      data: data,
      options: Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader:"application/json",
            HttpHeaders.acceptHeader:"*/*"
      }));
    debugPrint(response.toString());
    if(response.statusCode != 200) {
      debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());
    }
    return response;
```