# Server API not accept JSON edcoded data Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Edit:
After hours of work, i might because when i send "content-type": "application/json", it send "application/json; charset=utf-8" to server. How to remove **; charset=utf-8** from header?

Edit2:
The problem is because flutter send charset=utf-8 in Content-type. I fix by contact my backend developer to allow "application/json; charset=utf-8" in Content-type header

I send post request to server, return error

```
{"error":"true","code":"30","message":" Data must JSON"}
```

This is my code:

```
Future<void> _getToken() async {
final url =
    Uri.parse("http://apimobile.xxxx.co.id/Apimobile/auth");
final Map<String, String> data = {
  "username": "xxxx",
  "password": "xxxx"
};
try {
  final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
      },
      body: jsonEncode(data));
  print(response.body);
  final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  _token = responseData["message"];
} catch (error) {
  throw error;
 }
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code?

***The API work on Postman, ThunderClient VS Code, and React Native***

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you just need to use data.toJson() instead of jsonEncode(data).

Comment: @MoïseRajesearison can't use data.toJson in map: The method 'toJson' isn't defined for the type 'Map'. How to use it? 

Comment: You're right !!! And Have you already tried json.encode(data); ?

Comment: @MoïseRajesearison yes. already tried json.encode(data) but same result 

Comment: And try to change "final Map<String, String> data" to "final data"

Comment: @MoïseRajesearison still not work too

Answer (score 1):

Create model like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';

LoginData loginDataFromJson(String str) => LoginData.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginDataToJson(LoginData data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginData {
  LoginData({
    required this.username,
    required this.password,
  });

  final String username;
  final String password;

  factory LoginData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginData(
        username: json["username"],
        password: json["password"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "username": username,
        "password": password,
      };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '$runtimeType($username, $password)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other is LoginData) {
      return username == other.username && password == other.username;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash2(username, password);
}
```

And now you can write your code like this:

```
Future<void> _getToken() async {
final url =
    Uri.parse("http://apimobile.xxxx.co.id/Apimobile/auth");
final LoginData data = LoginData(
  username: "xxxx",
  password: "xxxx"
);
try {
  final response = await http.post(url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
      },
      body: data.toJson());
  print(response.body);
  final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
  _token = responseData["message"];
} catch (error) {
  throw error;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But still not work. It might because when i send "content-type": "application/json", it send "application/json; charset=utf-8" to server. How to remove ; charset=utf-8 from header?

Comment: You can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278258/http-post-with-json-on-body-flutter-dart

Comment: I fix with contact my backend developer to allow application/json; charset=utf-8 in request header. Thanks for help bro :)

Answer (score 0):

The headers field in the `http.post` method has to be changed to have `Content-Type` equal to application/json and accept equal to application/json.

```
Future<void> _getToken() async {
      final url =
          Uri.parse("http://apimobile.xxxx.co.id/Apimobile/auth");
      final Map<String, String> data = {
        "username": "xxxx",
        "password": "xxxx"
      };
      try {
        final response = await http.post(url,
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              "accept": "application/json",
            },
            body: jsonEncode(data));
        print(response.body);
        final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        _token = responseData["message"];
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. What should i change in my code? 

Comment: It seems your code is correct. Hmm recommendedto check API Documentation ensure you are sending the correct format of data and headers

Answer (score 0):

Try encode your data using convert

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

//...

const JsonEncoder encoder = JsonEncoder();
final response = await http.post(url,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json",
    },
    body: encoder.convert(data)
);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Hi. thanks for your answer. But still not work 